# PHP Array Undefined offset

Tags: php, xml, laravel, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an XML document which doesn't have a constant structure, some nodes may or may not exist, but my parsing is coded in a way that I always expect the whole structure. I've tried this:

```
$mKvFudbalDC->c4 = null;
$mKvFudbalDC->c5 = null;
$mKvFudbalDC->c6 = null;
$mKvFudbalDC->c68 = null;
$mKvFudbalDC->c69 = null;
$mKvFudbalDC->c4 = $choices[0]->attributes()->value;
$mKvFudbalDC->c5 = $choices[1]->attributes()->value;
$mKvFudbalDC->c6 = $choices[2]->attributes()->value;
$mKvFudbalDC->c68 = $choices[3]->attributes()->value;
$mKvFudbalDC->c69 = $choices[4]->attributes()->value

$mKvFudbalDC->save();
```

I was thinking that setting the variables to null will fix the problem, but no. For an example, if `$choices[4]->attributes()->value`
doesn't exist, I get an Undefined offset exception. I tried with `isset()` in an if/else statement, but it turns out I had to do that with each and every member of the array, and it slows down the parsing and/or crashes nginx/apache and doesn't parse the XML to the end. Can this be overriden in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary operator to look if it isset and if not set the variable to 0 or -1 like this:

```
$mKvFudbalDC->c4 = (isset($choices[0]->attributes()->value) ? $choices[0]->attributes()->value : 0);
//...
```

**EDIT:**

Otherwise try it like this:

```
$mKvFudbalDC->c69 = (isset($choices[4]) ? $choices[4]->attributes()->value : 0);
//...
```

Comment: No, still the same, Undefined offset on that line.

Comment: @user1481792 Please show us the exact error message you get

Comment: http://imgur.com/uKU5PQS,sqTX0pB#0
The ErrorException on line 207

And the code
http://imgur.com/uKU5PQS,sqTX0pB#1

Comment: @user1481792 Did you used my example line with every index? e.g. `$mKvFudbalDC->c69 = (isset($choices[4]->attributes()->value) ? $choices[4]->attributes()->value : 0);`

Comment: Yes, it's in the second image, throws the same error.

Comment: @user1481792 Try to change it to this: `$mKvFudbalDC->c69 = (isset($choices[4]) ? $choices[4]->attributes()->value : 0);` does that works, otherwise i have no idea

Comment: @user1481792 Glad that i could help you! Have a nice day :D (Just updated the answer)